# Realm database: login to server

Tags: xamarin.android, realm

I'm trying to login to Realm Object Server usin login and password:

```
    private async Task<User> Login()
    {
        var credentials = Credentials.UsernamePassword("smsuser@mail.ru", "smsuser", createUser: false);
        var authUrl = new Uri("http://neo.xxxxxx.ru:27080/auth");
        var user = await User.LoginAsync(credentials, authUrl);
        if (User.Current == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User.Current == null");
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User.Current != null");
            return user;
        }

    }
```

When login and password haven't any error all is Ok and I see message "User.Current != null" and application continues to work normally. But when login or password is wrong> the application freezes and message "User.Current == null" never appeared. Please, tell me when I made mistake?

Comment: awaiting `User.LoginAsync` will throw an exception if the credentials are invalid. That's why the rest of the method is never executed.

Comment: @Tayschrenn, so I need to use try/catch mechanism, yes?

Comment: Yes, you need try/catch to handle errors.

Comment: @Tayschrenn, thank you, I'll try it right now

Comment: @Tayschrenn, thank you! All is working now!